# Modify function getdomain, would need it without subdomain in PHP

Tags: php, dns, subdomain

I would need help with my code:
I have a function which only replaces thee www. with a blank space.

For example:
If I add the url:  www.testek.com 
The user will see **testek.com**

But if I add the url: s.dada.testek.com
The user will see **s.dada.testek.com**

So if we use the domain s.dada.testek.com I would like that the end user sees only **testek.com**.

But I would like to get only the main domain without any subdomains.

Code:

```
function getdomain($url){ 
    $parsed = parse_url($url); 
    return str_replace('www.','', strtolower($parsed['host'])); 
}
```

I saw a post but it won't work for me.

Thanks for the help!

Now I've changed the code to:

```
function getdomain($url){ 
    $parsed = parse_url($url); 
    $bits = explode(".",$parsed["host"]);
    $mainDomain = array_filter($bits, function ($i) use ($bits) {
         return $i >= count($bits)-2;
    }, array(
    'www.rover.ebay.com' => 'ebay.com',
    's.click.aliexpress.com' => 'aliexpress.com', );

    return implode(".", $mainDomain);
}
```

Am I thinking the right way?

Because now the end user sees like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/JddKB.jpg

Comment: So what qualifies as a main domain? e.g. in `www.google.com` the answer is obviously `google.com` but how about in a hypothetical `www.beta.google.com` is it still `google.com` or is it `beta.google.com` ?

Comment: How to say what qualifies. Like you asked, it would be allways google.com

Comment: So `www.google.co.uk` would be `co.uk`? You need a better problem statement.

Comment: I won't need those domain names...because i will use them only from ebay.com aliexpress.com and amazon.com.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to get the last 2 segments of a URL main domain name then you can do the following:

```
function getdomain($url){ 
    $parsed = parse_url($url); 
    $bits = explode(".",$parsed["host"]);
    $mainDomain = array_filter($bits, function ($i) use ($bits) {
         return $i >= count($bits)-2;
    }, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY );

    return implode(".", $mainDomain);
}
```

See how it works in https://eval.in/636860

Unfortunately most of the times there's no "catch all" solution and you have to do a lot of hard-coded things. e.g. the UK has `.co.uk` but France just `.fr` so depending on that you may need the last 3 or even 4 segments.

Comment: yeah this is the way i want to use it.

Comment: what should i put into the array filter key? the domain names?

Comment: @Daichisan I'm not sure I've understood what you're asking

Comment: Look at the code in the question which I've updated. If  I implement that code I'm getting nothing... I've also added a screen from which you can see what I wanted to change.

Comment: I don't understand why you changed the code like that. `getdomain` is meant to accept a single URL and return the domain of that URL. If you have more than one URL you need to call `getdomain` for each one separately

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed it like this:

```
function getdomain($url){ 
    $parsed = parse_url($url); 
    $replace = array ("rover.", "www.", "s.click.");
    return str_replace($replace,'', strtolower($parsed['host'])); 
}
```

I've created an array with the "subdomains" which I don't want to be shown.
And now it works ok.

apokryfos thanks for your support and for opening my mind :)